# Using Microsoft Graph API to Query Certain Sharepoint URIs with .aspx Extensions

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have a question about sharepoint combined with the graph API. I'm trying to do a GET request against a sharepoint site, but it doesn't populate when the url has a .aspx extension. For example if I do 'GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/hostname.sharepoint.com:/sites/blablabla/UK' this populates a response fine, but if I do 'GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/hostname.sharepoint.com:/sites/blablabla/UKDTAppKZ/something.aspx' then I get a 404 error suggesting this site doesn't exist... Could I get some clarification on how to use graph GET queries with sharepoint urls, specifically .aspx extensions?

Comment: You need to submit one feature request for this in the UserVoice. Graph API is in devoleping, it have not support all thing……

Answer (score 0):

In your first URL you're accessing the Site object for the /sites/blablabla/UK sub site, so you should get back a valid site object (assuming the URL is correct) as you indicated.  To access the files in that site you need to access the Drives (Document Libraries) and then get the children or the specific item you're looking for.  So the URL would look something like:

Path support isn't always consistent right now so wherever possible I like to use IDs if I know them.
So with an ID it would be:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/HOSTNAME.sharepoint.com,SITECOLLECTIONGUID,SITEGUID/drives/DRIVEID/root/children

OR

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/HOSTNAME.sharepoint.com,SITECOLLECTIONGUID,SITEGUID/drives/DRIVEID/items/ITEMID

For Pages specifically though I would take a look at the Beta Pages API we added recently.  If you want to do any operations (like publishing) to the page you'll want that API instead of the basic drive API.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried to find my site guid using this guide: https://support.cloudhq.net/how-to-find-guids-of-sharepoint-sites/ . This method didn't allow us obtain any xml when attached to a .aspx extension. Is there another way to find guid for a .aspx uri?